# How to change the background

Tags: python, streamlit

I am new to streamlit and wanted to know that Is there any way to change the background of the streamlit app ?

i have tried uisng this in my code its not showing any error but it also not working

Let me know how to change the background any idea would be appreciated

```
page_bg_img = '''
    <style>
    body {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542281286-9e0a16bb7366");
    background-size: cover;
    }
    </style>
    '''
    
    st.markdown(page_bg_img, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Orignial code:

```
import cv2
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np 
from PIL import Image


def cartoonization (img):

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)      
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 9) 
    edges = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 9, 9) 
    color = cv2.detailEnhance(img, sigma_s=10, sigma_r=0.15)
    cartoon = cv2.bitwise_and(color, color, mask=edges)
    return cartoon

###############################################################################
    
st.write("""
          # Cartoonize Your Image!

          """
          )

st.write("This is an app to turn your photos into cartoon")

file_image = st.camera_input(label = "Take a pic of you to be sketched out")

if file_image:
    input_img = Image.open(file_image)
    final_sketch = cartoonization(np.array(input_img))
    st.write("**Output Pencil Sketch**")
    one = st.columns(1,gap="small")
    st.image(final_sketch, use_column_width=True)
else:
     st.write("You haven't uploaded any image file")
```

Comment: Did you try to use `.body` instead of `body`?

Comment: I have tried still getting the same output @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: What about `canvas` instead of `body`?Just seen [this thread](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/are-you-using-html-in-markdown-tell-us-why/96/62?page=4).

Comment: canvas also not working @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can use your local image to the background

```
import cv2
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np 
from PIL import Image
import base64

def image_local(image_file):
    with open(image_file, "rb") as image_file:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    st.markdown(
    f"""
    <style>
    .stApp {{
        background-image: url(data:image/{"png"};base64,{encoded_string.decode()});
        background-size: cover
    }}
    </style>
    """,
    unsafe_allow_html=True
    )
image_local('photo.png')    


def cartoonization (img):

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)      
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 9) 
    edges = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 9, 9) 
    color = cv2.detailEnhance(img, sigma_s=10, sigma_r=0.15)
    cartoon = cv2.bitwise_and(color, color, mask=edges)
    return cartoon

###############################################################################
    
st.write("""
          # Cartoonize Your Image!

          """
          )

st.write("This is an app to turn your photos into cartoon")

file_image = st.camera_input(label = "Take a pic of you to be sketched out")

if file_image:
    input_img = Image.open(file_image)
    final_sketch = cartoonization(np.array(input_img))
    st.write("**Output Pencil Sketch**")
    one = st.columns(1,gap="small")
    st.image(final_sketch, use_column_width=True)
else:
     st.write("You haven't uploaded any image file")
```